# Avoiding TextInput focus on React Native Android

Tags: react-native

The following code works fine on iOS

`<TextInput pointerEvents={"none"} value={textValue2} onPress={something}></TextInput>`

But on android it would seem that `pointerEvents` isnt supported.

I tried wrapping the `TextInput` around a `TouchableOpacity` but sadly (albeit reasonably) focus is still given to it when pressed. Is there anyway i can detect the press without triggering the focus? Other props i've tried that didnt work:

`editable={false}
selectTextOnFocus={false}`

Comment: One simple hack could be to add a transparent view on top of this textInput and handle onClick of the transparent view as required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
You can use Keyboard API.

import { Keyboard, TextInput } from 'react-native';

<TextInput
  onSubmitEditing={Keyboard.dismiss}
/>
```

Please see the full example in [react native offical document](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboard.html).

Comment: Doesnt seem to work, additionally tried the same with onFocus but nada